# Multiple refs inside a Vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a polygonCrop component which one of them has a ref with canvas property, I am using each component in separate crop functions on two button components so I would like to know how to use multiple refs with multiple components in Vue.js?

```
<polygonCrop 
    :canvasClass="'some-class'"
    :height="600"
    :imageSource="imgSrc"
    :showCanvas="show"
    :showPointer="showPointer"
    :width="800"
    ref="canvas"
></polygonCrop>
<polygonCrop 
    :canvasClass="'some-class'"
    :height="600"
    :imageSource="imgSrc1"
    :showCanvas="show"
    :showPointer="showPointer"
    :width="800"
    ref="canvas1"
></polygonCrop>
...
<b-button @click.prevent="crop" variant="success">Crop</b-button>
<b-button @click.prevent="crop1" variant="success">Crop</b-button>
...
crop: function () {
    this.$refs.canvas.crop();
    this.resultImage = this.$refs.canvas.resultImage;
    this.show = false;
    this.showResult = true;
},
crop1: function () {
    this.$refs.canvas1.crop();
    this.resultImage1 = this.$refs.canvas1.resultImage;
    this.show = false;
    this.showResult = true;
},
```

I am using multiple canvases like `canvas` and `canvas1` but I want to know if this is the right way to do this?

Comment: use v-for to avoid repetition and crop function should be one which takes ref as an argument

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would not recommend using this approach if you have multiple elements with unique props for each element, what you should be doing is to create an array that contains multiple objects, each object includes the data needed for that canvas. for example:

```js
data(){
  return {
      canvases:[
        {
          class: 'class-name',
          imgSrc: 'image-source',
          width: 800,
          height: 600,
          ....
        },
        {
          class: 'class-name-2',
          imgSrc: 'image-source-2',
          width: 800,
          height: 600,
        }
         ....
      ]
  }
}
```

and then loop through this array:

```html
<!-- 5 elements -->
<polygonCrop 
             v-for="(canvas, i) in canvases"
             :key="i"
             :canvasClass="canvas.class"
             :height="canvas.height"
             :imageSource="canvas.imgSrc"
             :showCanvas="show(i)"
             :showPointer="showPointer"
             :width="800"
             :ref="'canvas-' + i"
></polygonCrop>
```

**However if you wanna keep your code structure the way it is, here is a solution for you**

For the DOM, use a `v-for` loop with dynamic ref binding, for the image sources use a method to match the data variables name:

```html
<!-- 5 elements -->
<polygonCrop :canvasClass="'some-class'"
             :height="600"
             :imageSource="getSource('imgSrc' + n)"
             :showCanvas="show"
             :showPointer="showPointer"
             :width="800"
             v-for="n in 5"
             :key="n"
             :ref="'canvas-' + n"
></polygonCrop>
<b-button @click.prevent="crop(n)" variant="success" v-for="n in 5">Crop {{n}}</b-button>
```

and use only one crop function, with a parameter:

```js
// methods
crop: function (n) {
    const canvas = 'canvas-' + n 
    this.$refs[canvas].crop();
    this.resultImage = this.$refs[canvas].resultImage;
    this.show = false;
    this.showResult = true;
},
getSource : function(img) {
  return this[img]
}
```

Comment: Hi, for your second approach, I am getting below error 15:1  error  Custom elements in iteration require 'v-bind:key' directives  vue/valid-v-for

Comment: @Mah Yes the key binding is important but not necessary, just bind the `n` value as a key, I've updated the answer implementing that.